# Gramian of a permutation group orbit

Tags: finite-groups, permutations, matrix-theory

let $W\in R^{d\times k},d>k$. Suppose that the associated gramian has the following structure:
$$
W^TW=(P_{1}t,\cdots,P_{k}t)
$$
with the set $\{P_{i},i=1,\cdots,k\}$ forming a group of permutations (on $k$ objects) and $t\in R^k$.

1) Is it true that $W$ must then be an orbit of a permutation group up to an isometry, i.e.

$$
W=UO,\;\;\; O=(\bar{P}_{1}s,\cdots,\bar{P}_{k}s),\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;U^TU=Id
$$
with the set $\{\bar{P}_{i},i=1,\cdots,k\}$ forming a group of permutations (on $d$ objects) and $s\in R^d$.?

2) Which other condition(s) (besides the particular structure of the gramian) should I had to have $U=Id$, i.e. $W=O$?

Thanks a lot!

Fabio

Comment: think of the case $k=1$. Surely $W$ need not have any symmetry in it at all.

Comment: Hi, I guess in that case P=e the identity,which is  a permutation